# How to get .msi running location in wix installer?

Tags: c#, wix

In wix dialog i have upload button to upload companylogo...i need to show this image in next dialog after clicking next button.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please *show your research* to avoid that other people research and propose stuff that you have already tried unsuccessfully. E.g. what search terms have you googled for? Which sites/tutorials/blogs have you visited which may help but don't have the complete solution? I'd suggest you [edit] your question to include that information, it will improve your chances of getting a helpful answer, reduces hassle for others and makes your question more userful for others. Also: Have you checked out our [posting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: You might be able to do so by modifying the Binary table by a custom action. Alternatively, you might consider using a Burn bootstrapper and code your UI there (e.g. using WPF) instead in the rather limited Windows Installer internal UI.

Comment: Can you put this functionality in your main application instead? Much easier in terms of implementation, debugging and testing.

Comment: I am creating only one application.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using the default wix ui dialogs or you have customized the UI dialogs.

If you are using the default dialogs then you can set any of the below two variables:

- WixUIBannerBmp    this is wixvariable for Top banner.
  Size: 493 × 58
- WixUIDialogBmp    this us wixvariable for Background bitmap used on the welcome and completion dialogs
  Size:493 × 312

Syntax :

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="..\images\banner.bmp" />
```

You can get path of image from custom action and then that path can be set while setting wix variable.

E.g. if your path propery name is BrowsedFilePath, then the syntax would be

Syntax :

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="[BrowsedFilePath]" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: uploaded image is not a banner, just logo of user company. I need to display that in next dialog with selected path.